# Display only one error with jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to display one error message at the top, if validation fails. I don't want to use `errorPlacement` option. Instead I want to show the message in the Bootstrap alert.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/role" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="roles_form">
    <div class="alert alert-danger vd_hidden">
        <span class="vd_alert-icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle vd_red"></i></span> 
        Please select a role.
    </div>
    <input id="role_administrator" name="role" type="radio" value="administrator">
    <label for="role_administrator">Administrator</label>
    <input id="role_manager" name="role" type="radio" value="manager"> 
    <label for="role_manager">Manager</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my JavScript:

```
var roles_form = $('#roles_form');
var error_roles_form = $('.alert-danger', roles_form);

roles_form.validate({
    focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
    debug: true,

    rules: {
        role: "required"
    },

    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit
        error_roles_form.fadeIn(500);
    },

});
```

This does not work. Neither it does any validation (form gets submitted, if I remove the `debug` option) nor does it show any error.

**Update:**
After looking at the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468645/225790) provided by Sparky, I realised that I am using a plugin to hide radio elements and replace with a style-able object. As the radio elements were hidden, jQuery Validation failed to validate them properly with my JavaScript code. What surprised me is that it did not show any JavaScript error, even with debug mode on.

Comment: You should always proof-read your OP before walking away.  Your HTML was invisible because of a formatting error.

Comment: Oops! I don't know what happened. Can't notice any difference in the revision. Anyways, thank you for fixing it.

Comment: There was a line return missing above the HTML code block preventing anyone from seeing the HTML in the OP.

Comment: I see. It was showing correctly on the preview. After posting, I did not notice it, as I got distracted with something else. Thank you for fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:**

> *"This does not work. Neither does any validation (form gets submitted, if I remove the `debug` option) nor [does] it shows any error."*

Actually, the code you posted is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/TTJB7/

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"I want to display one error message at the top, if validation fails. I don't want to use `errorPlacement` option."*

For placing the error message into a box, you'll need [the `errorLabelContainer` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorlabelcontainer).  So instead of the default behavior of putting error messages next to each input (`errorPlacement`), the `errorLabelContainer` will put the messages into one specified container that is hidden/shown automatically.

```
var roles_form = $('#roles_form');
var error_roles_form = $('.alert-danger', roles_form);

roles_form.validate({
    focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        role: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        role: "Please select a role."
    },
    errorLabelContainer: error_roles_form  // puts the error messages into this container
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="roles_form">
    <div class="alert alert-danger vd_hidden"></div>
    <input id="role_administrator" name="role" type="radio" value="administrator" />
    <input id="role_manager" name="role" type="radio" value="manager" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/TTJB7/1/**

For all other available callback options, [see the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate).

Comment: Thank you for your help. After looking at your solution, I tried to solve my issue. And I found that the issue is with something else. I use a plugin to hide radio elements and replace with a style-able object. As the radio elements were hidden, jQuery Validation failed to validate them properly with my JavaScript code. What surprised me is that it did not show any JavaScript error, even with debug mode on.

Comment: Now I realised why jQuery Validation did not validate the element. As the element was hidden, it was ignoring them. So, no validation, no error (on debug).

Comment: @Debiprasad, I fully answered your question as you presented it.  Your `radio` buttons were not hidden and I showed you how to properly place the error messages into a single box.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Then I realised my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When I realised that the actual problem is with the hidden radio elements, I did a little research and solved the issue.

First I applied `ignore` to "" so that it will not ignore `hidden` elements and validate them.

Then I need to stop default error message to appear after the element. So I assigned an empty function to that option.

Here is my final JavaScript code:

```
roles_form.validate({
    focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
    ignore: "",

    rules: {
        role: "required"
    },

    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit
        error_roles_form.fadeIn(500);
    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {}

});
```

Comment: 1) **This answer has absolutely nothing to do with your original question**, _"Display only one error with jQuery Validation"_, where [the code you posted was not broken](http://jsfiddle.net/TTJB7/). 2) The proper format is `ignore: []`, not `ignore: ""`  3) It's best to use the appropriate options and callback options for handling messages... you should never have an empty function.  (At least use a `return false`)